# Reading BOOL from plist, writing over it with new value

Tags: iphone

I've established how to read a BOOL from a plist, but I don't know how to write over the BOOL value I originally read.

The BOOL I'm reading is buried within my plist. When the view loads I take a dictionary from the plist that contains all the info for the view (detail view at the end of a drill down), and the BOOL is inside that dictionary. I can change the value of the BOOL in the dictionary once it's been brought into the app, but I don't know how to write this back to the postion within the plist.

Hopefully this is making sense?

Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write a NSDictionary to a Property List:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FileName.plist"];

NSDictionary *myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"myKey"];
[myDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Read the Boolean:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FileName.plist"];

NSDictionary *myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
BOOL myBool = [[myDict objectForKey:@"myKey"] boolValue];
```

---

You can also put the filePath code into this function:

```
- (NSString *)getFilePath {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FileName.plist"];
return filePath;
}
```

And use it like this: (for reading)

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self getFilePath]];
BOOL myBool = [[myDict objectForKey@"myKey"] boolValue];
```

And this: (for writing)

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"myKey"];
[myDict writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

Comment: BOOL myBool = [[myDict objectForKey@"myKey"] boolValue]; 
is missing a colon between objectForKey and @"myKey"

Answer (score 2):

For writing BOOL to .plist use below code

```
NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
[myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"LSUIElement"];
[myDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:NO];
```

Also have look at the [post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/164434-writing-out-bool-value-to-plist.html)

Comment: I know how to do this, but I always assumed it wouldn't remember the position I was within the plist, and instead would write the dictionary to the root of the plist?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
 -(void) setStringToPropertyList:(NSString*) pList withKey:(NSString*)key andValue:(NSString*)val{
//the path.
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:pList];
//read the dictionary.
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
//modify the desired key of the dictionary.
[temp setValue:val forKey:key];
//rewrite the diccionary again.
if([temp writeToFile: plistPath atomically:YES]){
   NSLog(@"setStringToPropertyList: pList updated");
}else{
   NSLog(@"setStringToPropertyList: error writing the file");
}
//memory management
if(!temp) [temp release];
}
```

This function allows you to write properties to a pList, parameteres:

pList = name of the file

key = key of the property

val = value of the property

Hope it helps.